# How to reduce a JMeter log?

Tags: performance, testing, jmeter

I have scheduled some nightly (12h) and weekly (60h) JMeter tests. The tests are triggered by Hudson CI server using Maven JMeter plugin.

My problem is that logs from JMeter become very long (~1GB for each nightly and 3GB for weekly tests). I would like to configure JMeter to not log sub-requests (images, css, js...), because these values don't mean much to me, and there are 18 sub-requests for each request that I make (so, if I have ~700.000 requests during weekly tests, I get 12.600.000 lines of logged requests)

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're *not* talking about the jmeter.log created by log4j (as it doesn't seem to log a great deal) and are talking about writing results to a file (from a listener, such as *View Results in Table*), which by default logs every request (in an XML format).

Do you

1. have separate HTTP request samplers for each image/javascript/css
   file
2. have one HTTP request sampler for the whole page and have ticked the *Retrieve All
   Embedded Resources from HTML Files* option?

If it's the latter, you should untick the `Save Sub Results (XML)` option on the export file configuration (or set `jmeter.save.saveservice.subresults=false` in your [jmeter.properties](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter) file.)

Alternatively consider disabling embedded resources altogether (assuming it's not relevant to the purpose of your test), so you'll only get output for the main page, not all of the embedded resources.

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about XML results log and the second option (one sampler with embedded resources). Is there a way not to lose those embedded resources (if I have no other options, I'll get rid of them, but I'd really like not to do that)?

Comment: Have you tried unticking the `Save Sub Results (XML)` option on the export file configuration?

Comment: Hmm.. Dumb question, but.. where's that configuration? I'm not using any listeners (Maven plugin somehow takes care of the logging results). The test consists of a thread group -> loop controller -> Http request (and a cookie manager, uniform random timer and user defined variables elements)

Comment: If you have a [jmeter.properties](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter) file, I believe you can set the following property `jmeter.save.saveservice.subresults=false`